# Brakes messed up after service

Tags: brakes, abs, speedometer, clicking

I recently brought my truck to a shop to fix my ABS that displayed the "ABS indicator" light intermittently, fix/adjust my speedometer which was reading wrong, and replace some burned-out lights in my dashboard.

All they did was put new abs sensor in the rear. As I leave the ABS light comes on again. As I braked for a red light I noticed a clicking that gets worse the slower the car is moving. I can feel clicking if i push the brakes all the way down and let the pedal slightly. A few clicks in and its like the resistance pressure goes away and it's soft.

At this point the brakes are very "grabby" and it's very difficult to stop without locking up the wheels.

They also said the reluctor ring is missing two teeth but it's not clear why they didn't replace it.

Comment: It would really help if you edited this question and removed all the "commentary" about speeding tickets, annoyance with the shop, and so on.  Those don't really have anything to do with the actual problem you're having with the brakes and also make it difficult to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: A few paragraphs would not go amiss either...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you taken it back to the workshop?  Their work ought to be warranted and if there is a clicking noise, they should investigate and rectify it free of charge if it's their mistake.

Comment: A bad wheel speed sensor can cause the traction control & ABS to activate at inappropriate times. That is NOT safe. My G35 loved to lock up the front RH wheel when making slow right turns. Nearly slammed into a Civic because of that.

Comment: It's also not clear how they knew that the tone ring (aka, reluctor) was missing teeth. They'd have to open up the hub to see that. Modern hubs are typically sealed units that, without great determination, cannot be repaired.

Answer (score 1):

Find another shop. Any shop that would replace an ABS sensor and release the vehicle knowing that teeth were missing from the ring is a shop that doesn't know what they're doing.